# Как передать $_POST в 403.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

Есть сайт статичных страничек, куда я пытаюсь добавить микро-cms с помощью строк в 
.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /403.php
```

т.е. все запросы на несуществующие страницы будут перенаправлены на движок 403.php.
Все было отлично, пока не взялся за формы - оказывается, если передавать данные не конкретному скрипту, а текущей странице, например так:

```
<form action='". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ."' method=post>
```

то движок данные не получает, ему нужно:

```
<form action='/403.php' method=post>
```

Возможно ли настроить .htaccess так, чтобы движок всегда получал `$_POST`?

Comment: Вероятнее всего- нельзя. [Здесь][1] такой же вопрос.
[1]:http://habrahabr.ru/qa/9872/

Comment: Спасибо. Пойду, выпью с горя.

Comment: Вообще правильней оставлять action="" или action=".", тогда обработчиком формы будет текущий скрипт. Кто вас такому научил вообще?

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

Вообще правильней оставлять `action=""` или `action="."`, тогда обработчиком формы будет текущий скрипт.